# How to dynamically add <p:tab> to <p:wizard> in a loop

Tags: jsf, dynamic, primefaces, tabs, wizard

I would like to dynamically add `<p:tab>` components to `<p:wizard>` component in a loop.

I tried using `<ui:repeat>` inside and outside `<p:wizard>` component.

```
<p:wizard>
    <ui:repeat value="#{tabBean.tabs}" var="tab">
        <p:tab title="#{tab.tabname}">
    </ui:repeat>
</p:wizard>
```

```
<ui:repeat value="#{tabBean.tabs}" var="tab">
    <p:wizard>
        <p:tab title="#{tab.tabname}">
    </p:wizard>
</ui:repeat>
```

None of both attempts work. How can I achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<p:wizard>` only understands `<p:tab>` children. It doesn't understand an `<ui:repeat>` child. You need to create physical `<p:tab>` children in the JSF component tree as immediate child of the `<p:wizard>` component.

The `<c:forEach>` taghandler is capable of doing that.

```
<p:wizard>
    <c:forEach items="#{tabBean.tabs}" var="tab">
        <p:tab title="#{tab.tabname}">
    </c:forEach>
</p:wizard>
```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: But keep in mind that you cannot add a tab while in the process of executing a wizard. The `c:foreach` loop is executed once, at viewbuildtime. So 'dynamically adding' is more 'dynamically creating once'

Comment: @Kukeltje: Just rebuild the view after doing that. Can be done by `setViewRoot(getViewId())`.

Comment: Isn't that the same as not doing ajax? Just a full page refresh? That is most of the time not what (imo) people mean by dynamically adding. Though this case may differ…

Comment: @Kukeltje: Nope, it's entirely server side. Only view scoped beans will die and get recreated, but that's a different problem :) A full page reload can also, but you know, it's clumsy.

Comment: :-)... But you still get all tabs transferred as html (whole page I assume, or is e.g. an `update="wizardId"` still honoured?) That is more what I meant to imply.

Comment: @Kukeltje: As said, it's entirely server side. Basically just the JSF component tree (and state) gets refreshed. That's it. Navigation/rendering/ajax-updates etc remain unaffected.